# Fetch data from second table based on first table

Tags: mysql

I'm new to the world of databases and I've just started making my first DB powered site with php and MySQL.

I've got it working with data from one table but now I need to get a url to the users school, which is in a second table. Based on which school the user has saved in the first table. Everytime I try this method: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp inside the registered.php the whole page goes blank. The connection to the database is made from a connect.php file which I included in both index.php and registered.php

Explanation, the user logs into the page at index.php, that page sets a cookie with the users school which it gets from the users table. The user gets redirected to registered.php where I want to get the school's url (and some more things) for the users school. It's very hard to explain, I hope you get it.. 
 Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that you have a problem in your PHP and not the database... you have some syntax error in your code and that's why you see a blank page. If you're doing this on your own machine, for development and debugging purposes you can configure PHP so that it prints errors out directly to the screen when you open the page in your browser instead of to the log.

You should also probably rethink your design as you should probably not store user details into a cookie (why not in $_SESSION, for example?), but I don't think that's a subject for this board...

Comment: Sorry, it is a session, did I mention that I'm the newbie of newbies?